# How can i click on textbox and see my calender

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, calendar

I have this code on my aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server" CssClass="input-date date-icn small-label" AutoCompleteType="BusinessZipCode" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" Visible="false" ></asp:Calendar>
&nbsp;<br />
<br />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and this is my code behind:

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    datepicker.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();   
}

protected void Show(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calendar1.Visible = true;    
}
```

how to write the event in the text box(in the aspx) so it can call the function "Show" and show the calender?

Comment: Why you are specifying `AutoCompleteType="BusinessZipCode"` for calendar ?!

Comment: i wil delete it... do you have a answer?

Comment: Try reading these >> http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_calendar.asp 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_calenders.htm

Comment: it doesn't help... i want to click on the textbox so the calender will show... what an event to write in the <asp:TextBox on.....="Show"> on what??

Comment: You need to use an [Ajax calendar](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_calendar.ashx) or [jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to have that functionality. I recommend you learn jQuery.. :)